# SMS intent not opening in android

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I am working on android application in which i am using SMS functionality. For this i am using intent to start an activity for native sms functionality.

My code is given below, but it gives me the following exception when it:

**Code:**

```
Intent intent_sms = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent_sms.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
int flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP;
intent_sms.setFlags(flags);
intent_sms.setData(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"));
startActivity(intent_sms);
```

**Error Log:**

```
01-17 07:40:41.261: E/AndroidRuntime(7674): 
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN 
dat=content://sms/inbox flg=0x34000000 }
```

Comment: so you need to open inbox directly ?

Comment: What you want to do? Opening Inbox or Send SMS

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
Intent intent_sms = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent_sms.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
intent_sms.putExtra("sms_body", "Hello"); 
startActivity(intent_sms);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code to open Inbox:

```
    Intent intent_sms = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent_sms.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent_sms.setClassName("com.android.mms",
            "com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList");
    startActivity(intent_sms);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
protected void idClicked() {
    Intent smsIntent;

    // At least KitKat
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        // Need to change the build to API 19
        String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(getActivity());

        smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        smsIntent.setType("text/plain");
        smsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mText);

        // Can be null in case that there is no default, then the user would be able to choose
        // any app that support this intent.
        if (defaultSmsPackageName != null) {
            smsIntent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
        }
        startActivity(smsIntent);

    // Older versions
    } else {
        smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", mText);
        if (smsIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(smsIntent);
        } else {
            UIUtils.showShortToast(getString(R.string.no_sms_app), getActivity());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working well 

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=vnd.android-dir/mms-sms (has extras) }